# Security to SDCard

Tags: java, android, android-sdcard

How to provide security in android sd card file. I am creating one application for E-book reading user can download it using that application and can read user can download it from `web-service` and after downloading it stores in SDCcard as `.epub file`

But i want to Provide it security that if one user download any book then other user cant copy from SDCard or they can not share file.

please one post me about this logic or if u have some example related this kindly post it.

Answer (score 0):

You can encrypt your epub file with your program using as a key some information that you can check. Of course, your application can be reversed but this will protect your files from the ordinary users.